# help with ajax/jquery form (submit data)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I tried to do some form (just submit data) . Application I'm write in rails, but i think it doesnt matter.

i have this js code:

```
    function closeForm(){
            var answer_text = $("#answer_text").val();

                if (answer_text != ''){
                    $(".messageSent").show("slow");
                    setTimeout('$(".messageSent").hide();$(".slide-out-div").slideUp("slow")', 1000);

            }
            else {
                alert('All fielsds are required!');
            }
        }
```

my form in rails

```
<span class="messageSent">Спасибо за ответ! Нам важно ваше мнение!</span>
<% form_for :home, :url => { :action => "create" }  do |f| %>
                <p><%= text_area(:answer, :text, :cols => 50, :rows => 10) %></p>


                    <p><%= submit_tag "Answer!", :class => "submit", :onclick => "closeForm()" %></p> 

                 <% end %>
```

Its okei, when I press submit and left textarea empty alert comes (that want I need), but when i press "OK" button, then page is realoading, but i dont want!! I want to say on page if i left some fields empty.

How i can figure this?

Please help , i 'm stuck with this about 4 hours..

UPDA: unfortunately it doesn't help :(
i think there a problem when i click on submit (form action /home/

create) :S? mby some conflicts with this function closeForm()?

UPD2: QUESTIONS IS CLOSED! all is done!

Comment: You have used a submit tag in your form. When the onclick does not return false, it will submit the form to the server. You can return false in the function to prevent submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your else block try:

```
 alert('All fielsds are required!');
 return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume this function is called when the form is submitted.  Change it to return false when you don't want the form to submit.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to reload the page then you can disable the submit button event using

```
        $(':submit').click(function(e)
{
            e.preventDefault();
}
```

this will prevent the form to be submit on server and you can check all the validation ..